# 301 redirect to a new .com.mx Domain Name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am moving from www.domain.com to www.domain.com.mx

I also had an SSL certificate on www.domain.com but not on www.domain.com.mx

I therefore need to redirect all http AND https requests to www.domain.com (or domain.com) to http://www.domain.com.mx

I am using these rules in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.domain.com.mx/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I suspect the issue is because domain.com contains domain.com.mx

Comment: What do you mean by it doesnt work? What is it doing? and are they on the same server?

Comment: Yes - same server. It is redirecting me from https://www.domain.com to https://www.domain.com.mx. It should 301 me to http://www.domain.com.mx

Comment: clear your browser cache and make sure you don't have any other rules for https

Comment: I am using https://httpstatus.io/ to test so caching shouldn't be an issue. These rules are at the very top of my .htaccess

Comment: BTW your 3 and 4 conditions are invalid and aren't helping. also don't test with 301, use 302 so it takes caching out of the mix until you are sure your rules work. Make sure your .htaccess file is being read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I just used this and it worked well:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com.mx/$1 [R=301,L]
```